# REGEX for a special phone number

Tags: php, regex

please I need a regular excepression to contrôl this special phone number :

```
00 66 6 06 06 06 06 (internationnal)
AND
00 666 6 06 06 06 06  (internationnal)
AND
06 06 06 06 06 (nationnal)
```

I've tried to make one :

```
^(\(\([0-9]*\)| [0-9]* ))?[0]?[0-9][0-9\  ]*$
```

But this is not really good.

Please masters any help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The numbers are only zeroes and sixes?

Comment: We need more details about your requirements... With the info we have the regular expression: `^(00 66 6 06 06 06 06|00 666 6 06 06 06 06|06 06 06 06 06)$` is all you need.

Comment: No it was just to simplify. All numbers are includes

Comment: Nevertheless you have a syntax error... `^(\(\([0-9]*\)| [0-9]* \))?[0]?[0-9][0-9\  ]*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but it may help:

```
^\d{2} (\d{2,3} \d )?\d{2} \d{2} \d{2} \d{2}$
```

Comment: Thank you Paulpro. This what I want ! +1

Comment: @SamiElHilali You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. Next time when you have a question about regular expressions try to come up with more varying examples (rather than all `06`) as well as examples of some things that you want to *not* match like not `066 06 06 06`. It will make it easier to determine exactly what your requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will do the trick for you:

```
^\d{2}\s\d{2,3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}(\s\d{2})?(\s\d{2})?$
```

and here is a [Rubular to prove it](http://rubular.com/r/zDOzI2Mq45). Please note that in the Rubular I didn't include the `$` because the text that's being searched is what you provided, but when doing the actual work you'd want that to be the end of the string.

Comment: I'm with you, but I don't like to make matching groups without a good reason and I've done this a bit different at the end: `^\d{2}\s\d{2,3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2}\s(?:\d{2})(?:\s\d{2}){2}?$`. Anyway I won't post another answer quite doubling your.